# MYSQL select data from url?

Tags: php, mysql

So for example I tried to select data from index.php?username=test
So the php will connect to the mysql db and look for test, if successful, it will print out the data.

I keep getting, "HTTP ERROR 500" "currently unable to handle this request."
my table is called "users"

Here's the code I've tried

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql="SELECT * from users where username = '".$_GET["username"]."' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "username: " . $row["username"]. " - Status: " . $row["status"]. ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I don't really know what to call this,  If anyone can help me with this, I would appreciate it so much

I've tried to google but because I don't know what this is called I didn't get exactly what I wanted

Comment: What isn't working with the code you have?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I keep getting, "HTTP ERROR 500" "currently unable to handle this request." my table is called "users"

Comment: How did you structure you table? please paste it here.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4ccf25ad684578bba67687ece474cd32

Comment: The _HTTP ERROR 500_ means you have a programming mistake in your code. Check that the mysqli connection is alive, the database has the right table names and put another double quote (`"`) at the end of the 7th line from down. It's probably a syntax error.

Comment: you have send username value by form tag with method and action attribute?

Comment: can u send the username value on the same page itself ?

Comment: Thank you all for helping, The 7th line needed another ".
How do i mark a comment as answer?

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with that code. You should be using prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Change this line:

```
echo "username: " . $row["username"]. " - Status: " . $row["status"]. ";
```

To:

```
echo "username: " . $row["username"]. " - Status: " . $row["status"];
```

You might try [PHP Code Checker](https://phpcodechecker.com/) to help find syntax errors.